# How can I save Google Chrome or Windows 10 Notification and export as CSV or other format?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, csv, notifications, action-center

I have so many Google Chrome notifications and after 20 notification Windows 10 doesn't allow me to see the older ones. That's why it has very necessary to save them. Is there any plugin that can save my Google Chrome notification in timely manner or will help me to save in CSV or other format?

Comment: This isn’t a feature of Windows at this time. A Chrome plug-in wouldn’t save Windows notifications

Comment: Is there any extension that can save notifications from Google Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to view Chrome browser notifications history?](https://superuser.com/questions/1035042/is-there-any-way-to-view-chrome-browser-notifications-history)

Answer (score 0):

This will not allow you to save them by itself but here are the logs for chrome notifications.

You could write a quick python script to parse and save the notifications.

C:\Users<YOUR USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Platform Notifications\000003.log

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).